How to extract 7z archive with LZMA compression
I have firmware file, which contains a raw MIPS32 binary code.
I used binwalk to scan for signatures binwalk -B -t image.out and for executable opcodes binwalk -A -t image.out
Top part of the output:
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
496           0x1F0           eCos kernel exception handler, architecture: MIPS, exception vector table base address: 0x80000300
25148         0x623C          Certificate in DER format (x509 v3), header length: 4, sequence length: 32
103948        0x1960C         Certificate in DER format (x509 v3), header length: 4, sequence length: 128
4340413       0x423ABD        bix header, header size: 64 bytes, header CRC: 0x431025AE, created: 1988-01-29 04:05:34, image size: 50335744 bytes, Data Address: 0x31A0030, Entry Point: 0x63FF008E, data CRC: 0x24000C3C, OS: NetBSD, image name: "B"

Then I tried to extract content: binwalk -e -z image.out
The extracted content is 8F2DB7.7z 7-zip archive and small data file 8F2DB7. I can't extract 7-zip archive:
$ 7z l 8F2DB7.7z

7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,4 CPUs Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-4005U CPU @ 1.70GHz (40651),ASM,AES-NI)

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 14996041 bytes (15 MiB)

Listing archive: 8F2DB7.7z

--
Path = 8F2DB7.7z
Open WARNING: Can not open the file as [7z] archive
Type = lzma

   Date      Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
                    .....         1792               8F2DB7
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
                                  1792     14996041  1 files

Warnings: 1

$ 7z x 8F2DB7.7z

7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,4 CPUs Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-4005U CPU @ 1.70GHz (40651),ASM,AES-NI)

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 14996041 bytes (15 MiB)

Extracting archive: 8F2DB7.7z
WARNING:
8F2DB7.7z
Can not open the file as [7z] archive
The file is open as [lzma] archive

--
Path = 8F2DB7.7z
Open WARNING: Can not open the file as [7z] archive
Type = lzma

ERROR: There are some data after the end of the payload data : 8F2DB7

Sub items Errors: 1

Archives with Errors: 1

Sub items Errors: 1

How I can extract that 7z archive?

7-zip 16.02 is quite old (released 2016), may be this problem has been fixed in newer versions?

Version was installed via Debian Synaptic package manager.

On the 7-Zip man page there is an option described for LZMA: -m0=lzma.
The man page of XZ Utils also describes an option for lzma decompression:
unlzma is equivalent to xz --format=lzma --decompress


The version of binwalk being used may not be the most recent release
https://github.com/ReFirmLabs/binwalk is no longer maintained, a maintained community fork can be found here: https://github.com/OSPG/binwalk
An alternative to binwalk called "unblob" has been developed, it can be found here: https://github.com/onekey-sec/unblob


I figured out, it's lzma archive and some data after lzma archive. This command worked for me: 7z x 8F2DB7.7z -t#. Extraction gives 2 files, 1.lzma: 1,8 KiB (empty file), and 2: 14,3 MiB (data file).  I will install latest binwalk fork from OSPG.
